# Persisting settings with JSON files

Tags: javascript, json, redis, settings, config

When I start my server, it downloads data about various cryptocurrencies. The data are only consumed by server for backend calculations, almost like a settings file. The data is rarely updated, but read very often. For some reason, I'm inclined to write these data to a JSON file, or a javascript object, instead of a redis or other db.

There are about 1000 cryptocurrency pairs with a few data fields each (minimum order size, etc).

Would persisting this data in JSON be a mistake?

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work I once wrote a equipment set builder for Old School Runescape where there was 12 categories and 14,000 individual items stored in JSON files as I felt a database to hold the values was a little over kill. Is there anything in particular concerning you?

Comment: I'm mostly just trying to figure out what the "standard" practice would be in this situation. Also I'm not sure how performant this would be.